# EWS - pull autolist contacts from exchange

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I tried googling it but didn't find any clear answer.
Is it possible to pull Autolist contacts from exchange using EWS Api? I know i can [search contacts by name](http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/tutorial-2.1/findcontacts1.html), but can i pull them by autolist?

Comment: Do you need the autocomplete list from Outlook or from OWA?

Answer (score 2):

Using [Exchange Service Managed API 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx) this should do the trick:

```
private static void ListOwaAutocompleteCache(ExchangeService service, string email)
{
    var folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, email);
    var userConfig = UserConfiguration.Bind(service, "OWA.AutocompleteCache", folderId, UserConfigurationProperties.All);

    var xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(userConfig.XmlData);
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml.Substring(1));
    var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("AutoCompleteCache/entry");
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["displayName"].Value + ", " + node.Attributes["smtpAddr"].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes It does. I have searched for days and the most elegant way to do this is what you see above.
 through managed API objects it was ridiculosly difficult 
With XmlDocument a hell of a lot easier thank you very much again